# How to iterate 100 files extracted from .tar.gz over a defined function Python

Tags: python, function, iteration

I have a .tar.gz file with thousands of .pdb files I need inside. Those.pdb files are one of the inputs of func1. I want to iterate func1 over 100 .pdb files each time and write it in func2.

I extracted the .pdb files from .tar.gz by

```
tar = tarfile.open("file_name.tar.gz", "r:gz")
```

and read in each file:

```
for member in tar.getmembers() :
      f = tar.extractfile(member)
```

I suppose I would have some structure like:

```
def func2(var1):
      for member in tar.getmembers():
          f = tar.extractfile(member)
  # I don't know how to do the 100 iterations
      def func1(var1, f):
```

As shown in the primary structure I have, I don't know how to do the 100 iterations, and I'm also not sure if I have the structure correct.
If you could answer this I would appreciate it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the question (edit title)? What is not working?

Comment: If your problem is to find your files, you should look into os.walk(). You can use it to "walk" in your directory and find files to use. i.e. "take all files ending with .tar.gz" :)

Comment: I just started coding and I don't know how to do the 100 times iteration part and I'm not sure if I have my basic code structure correctly.

Comment: @JingtongZhao circling back -- did either of the solutions help you?

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't quite work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate 100 times

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    pass # <- Code here
```

If you already have a list, it's better to iterate over the list

```
path_list = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3', ...]
for path in path_list:
    pass # <- Code here
```

I see something that won't work:

```
def func2(var1) # <- You forgot ":" 
      for member in tar.getmembers() : # <- Bad indentation
          f = tar.extractfile(member)
  # I don't know how to do the 100 iterations
      def func1(var1, f)
```

You forgot ":"

```
# Here is the basic structure. :)
def my_function():
    pass
```

Bad indentation

```
def func():
....a = 10 # <- 4 white spaces for indentation. Avoid tabulations, use spaces.
....do_something(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to "chunk" or "batch" the iteration over your list of files.

Here is a `chunks` function:

```
from itertools import (
    chain,
    islice
)

def chunks_iter(iterable, size=10):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:
        yield chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1))
```

You can use it like:

```
>>> l = list(range(100))
>>> for chunk in chunks_iter(l, 10):
...     print(list(chunk))
...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
[50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
[60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
[70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
[90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
>>>
```